# Помогите новичку: make px4_sitl gazebo - при выполении сборки, выдаёт ошибку

Tags: linux, ros

Пытаюсь по мануалу выполнить команду сборки для работы PX$ в системе имитационного моделирования. При работе выдаёт ошибки:

```
...$ make px4_sitl gazebo

...

[ 86%] Built target PreFlightCheck

CMake Error: The following variables are used in this project, but they are set to NOTFOUND.

Please set them or make sure they are set and tested correctly in the CMake files:
GSTREAMER_APP_LIBRARIES (ADVANCED)
    
linked by target "gazebo_airship_dynamics_plugin" in directory /home/rubikon/PX4-Autopilot/Tools/sitl_gazebo

...

-- Configuring incomplete, errors occurred!

See also "/home/rubikon/PX4-Autopilot/build/px4_sitl_default/build_gazebo/CMakeFiles/CMakeOutput.log".

See also "/home/rubikon/PX4-Autopilot/build/px4_sitl_default/build_gazebo/CMakeFiles/CMakeError.log".

[ 86%] Built target FlightTaskDescend


[ 88%] Built target FlightTaskUtility

make[4]: *** [platforms/posix/CMakeFiles/sitl_gazebo.dir/build.make:107: external/Stamp/sitl_gazebo/sitl_gazebo-configure] Ошибка 1

make[3]: *** [CMakeFiles/Makefile2:46822: platforms/posix/CMakeFiles/sitl_gazebo.dir/all] Ошибка 2

make[3]: *** Ожидание завершения заданий…

[ 88%] Built target FlightTaskFailsafe

[ 88%] Built target FlightTaskTransition

[ 88%] Built target modules__fw_pos_control_l1

make[2]: *** [CMakeFiles/Makefile2:34458: platforms/posix/CMakeFiles/gazebo.dir/rule] Ошибка 2

make[1]: *** [Makefile:12471: gazebo] Ошибка 2

make: *** [Makefile:233: px4_sitl] Ошибка 2
```